# SP2010: STS: 'SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool' - autostart error

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sts-securitytokenservice

**I am unable to create a web application from central administration**

Need to get FBA site working

**If I try to run SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc following error is displayed.**

> An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a policy export extension.
>   Extension: System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportSecurityBindingElement
>   Error: Security policy export failed. The binding contains a TransportSecurityBindingElement but no transport binding element that implements ITransportTokenAssertionProvider. Policy export for such a binding is not supported. Make sure the transport binding element in the binding implements the ITransportTokenAssertionProvider interface. ---->
>     System.InvalidOperationException: Security policy export failed. The binding contains a TransportSecurityBindingElement but no transport binding element that implements ITransportTokenAssertionProvider. Policy export for such a binding is not supported. Make sure the transport binding element in the binding implements the ITransportTokenAssertionProvider interface.
>      at   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportSecurityBindingElement.System.ServiceModel.Description.IPolicyExportExtension.ExportPolicy(MetadataExporter exporter, PolicyConversionContext policyContext)
>      at 
>     System.ServiceModel.Description.MetadataExporter.ExportPolicy(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)

**In event viewer below error is reported.**

> Event Id : 2303
>   Source: IIS-W3SVC-WP
>   There was an error during processing of the managed application service auto-start for application pool: 'SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool'.  Some application services may not have been processed correctly.  Please check the configuration for application service auto-start for the application(s) assigned to this application pool.  The data field contains the error code.

Already tried

- .NET framework 3.5 SP1 installed
- Disabling Forms authentication in SecurityTokenServiceApplication
- Ensuring the SecurityTokenServiceApplication is provisioned.

Any other solutions please.

I tried changing web.config for security token service to use IssuedToken security. With this change now I am able to see the service metadata. But below error is reported in the event viewer

Event Id: 8306
An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail..